# combine 2 SQL statements PHP OOP

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have these 2 functions executing 2 different queries:

```
public function getListPerPage($limit, $offset) {
    $dql = "SELECT b FROM Entities\Brain b WHERE b.status = '1' ORDER BY b.id DESC";
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
```

AND

```
public function getHiddenItems($limit, $offset, $brain_user_id) {
    $dql = "SELECT b FROM Entities\Brain b WHERE b.status = '2'
            AND b.user = :brain_user_id ORDER BY b.id DESC";
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
    $query->setParameter('brain_user_id', $brain_user_id);
```

I want to merge them in one function and one query, how can I combine these 2 statements in one query?

I tried using UNION as I read in many other questions and did not work for me.

The way I tried using UNION was:

```
"(SELECT b FROM Entities\Brain b WHERE b.status = '1')
  UNION (SELECT b FROM Entities\Brain b WHERE b.status = '2'
  AND b.user = :brain_user_id) ORDER BY b.id DESC";
```

Gave me an error, maybe my syntax was wrong?

Comment: Show your non-working version with UNION. Add it to your question by using [Edit].

Comment: mention that why do you want to mix two queries into one? do you want to have one database request for performance?

Comment: @PM77-1 added the UNION version

Comment: @Hamid for the function I'm creating I need it to be one request.

Comment: you have two different where condition so you can make one simple query with something like `SELECT b FROM Entities\Brain b WHERE (b.status = '2' AND b.user = :brain_user_id) or (b.status = '1') ORDER BY b.id DESC` then in the code separate each condition. It's easy to edit and also fast enough because you have one request to database engine and `foreach` of offline data is fast enough

Comment: Does it work w/o your `ODER BY`? If yes, remove alias from it.

Comment: @Hamid Worked perfectly! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Simply use one model method, store the result of each query on a separate variable and then return an array (or object, your choice) with both results to the controller.

For example:

```
public function getListAndHiddenItems($limit, $offset, $brain_user_id)
{
  $this->load->database();
  $this->db->select('fields');
  $this->db->from('table_one');
  $query = $this->db->get();

  $list = $query->result();

  $this->db->select('other_fields');
  $this->db->from('table_two');

  $query = $this->db->get();
  $hidden = $query->result();

  $result = array('list' => $list, 'hidden' => $hidden);

  return $result;
}
```

Add whatever clauses, joins, etc you need on each query. You would need to only call this single method from the controller and you'll get the two resultsets in different array elements